# getActivity null pointer exception after deleting fragment from FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-viewpager, fragment, facebook-login

I have a project on Android Studio and I stuck in this condition. The main idea, my application showing an order steps using wizard model. I use viewpager with FragmentStatePagerAdapter. I have some fragments, one fragment (6th fragment) is user's contact, appear when user not logged in.

User can login in this fragment (using facebook). After login success, this fragment should be removed. I have tried to remove this fragment, but an error occured. It tells that I have a null pointer exception when trying to get getActivity() value (at 7th fragment). I dont know why this error occured, because everthing okay when user not login at 6th fragment.

here are my codes

**MyAcitivity.java**

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ClassName className = new ClassName ();

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    MyActivity.PagerAdapter adapter;

    String type;


    ArrayList<Addons> listAddons = new ArrayList<Addons>();
    boolean changed = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);


        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_booking);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager.setPagingEnabled(false);
        adapter = new PagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                updateToolbar();
            }
        });

        updateToolbar();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

    }

    public void updateToolbar() {
        int position = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(adapter.getTitle(position));
        bookingProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        bookingProgressBar.setMax(adapter.getCount());
        bookingProgressBar.setProgress(position+1);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.close);

    }

    public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        List<Fragment> items = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> titles = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Boolean> instantiated = new ArrayList<>();

        public PagerAdapter(Activity activity, FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            items.add(new 1stFragment());
            items.add(new 2ndFragment());
            items.add(new 3rdFragment());
            items.add(new 4thFragment());
            items.add(new 5thFragment());
            items.add(new 6thFragment());
            items.add(new 7thFragment());
            items.add(new 8thFragment());

            titles.add(activity.getString(R.string.1));
            titles.add(activity.getString(R.string.2));
            titles.add(activity.getString(R.string.3));
            titles.add(activity.getString(R.string.4));
            titles.add(activity.getString(R.string.5));
            titles.add(activity.getString(R.string.6));
            titles.add(activity.getString(R.string.7));
            titles.add(activity.getString(R.string.8));

            instantiated.add(false);
            instantiated.add(false);
            instantiated.add(false);
            instantiated.add(false);
            instantiated.add(false);
            instantiated.add(false);
            instantiated.add(false);
            instantiated.add(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
            instantiated.set(position, false);
        }

        @Override
        public void finishUpdate(ViewGroup container) {
            super.finishUpdate(container);
            if(!instantiated.get(viewPager.getCurrentItem())){

                ((MyBaseFragment) items.get(viewPager.getCurrentItem())).setListAddons(listAddons);
                ((MyBaseFragment) items.get(viewPager.getCurrentItem())).setClassName(className);
                ((MyBaseFragment) items.get(viewPager.getCurrentItem())).instantiate();
                instantiated.set(viewPager.getCurrentItem(), true);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return items.get(position);
        }

        public String getTitle(int position){
            return titles.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return items.size();
        }

        public void removeContact(){
            items.remove(5);
            titles.remove(5);
            instantiated.remove(5);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            updateToolbar();
            ((MyBaseFragment) items.get(viewPager.getCurrentItem())).setListAddons(listAddons);
            ((MyBaseFragment) items.get(viewPager.getCurrentItem())).setClassName(className);
            ((MyBaseFragment) items.get(viewPager.getCurrentItem())).instantiate();
        }
    }

}
```

**6thFragment**
please focus at onCompleted callback first..

```
    public class 6thFragment extends MyBaseFragment {

        EditText emailEditText;
        private CallbackManager callbackManager;

        public 6thFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.6fragment_layout, container, false);
            emailEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText_email);

            if((new SessionPreference(getActivity())).isLoggedIn()){
                ((MyActivity.PagerAdapter)((ViewPager) view.getParent()).getAdapter()).removeContact();
            }
            callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

            LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
            loginButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
            loginButton.setFragment(this);
            loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile, email"));
            loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                            loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {

                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {

//**HERE THE MAIN QUESTION, AFTER USER SUCCESS LOGIN USING FACEBOOK**//
// **6th fragment should be removed**
                                    ((MyActivity.PagerAdapter)((ViewPager) view.getParent()).getAdapter()).removeContact();
                                }
                            });
                    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                    parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email");
                    request.setParameters(parameters);
                    request.executeAsync();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Login is canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Login is error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void instantiate() {
            //somecode
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isValid() {
            //some code
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChanged() {
            return emailEditText.getText().toString().trim().equals(generalCleaning.getEmail());
        }

        @Override
        public ClassName getClassName() {
            ///some code
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```

and then my **7thFragment** 
please focus at setPrice method first

```
public class 7thFragment extends MyBaseFragment implements View.OnClickListener{

        String planStr, planStrOld;

        LinearLayout weeklyLinearLayout, biweeklyLinearLayout, onetimeLinearLayout;
        RadioButton weeklyRadioButton, biweeklyRadioButton, onetimeRadioButton;

        RadioButton prevChecked;

        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        TextView priceTextView, dateTextView, timeTextView;

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMM d", Locale.getDefault()),
                timeFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());

        public 7thFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.7th_layout, container, false);

            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

            //codes

            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
            super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
            if(isVisibleToUser){
                setPrice();
                setRadioButton();
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void instantiate() {
            if(isAdded()){
                setPrice();
                setRadioButton();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isValid() {
            //codes
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChanged() {
            if(planStr.equalsIgnoreCase(planStrOld)){
                return true;
            }else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public ClassName getClassName() {
            //code
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            prevChecked.setChecked(false);

            if(view instanceof RadioButton) {
                ((RadioButton) view).setChecked(true);
                prevChecked = ((RadioButton) view);
            }else {
                LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) view;
                ((RadioButton) linearLayout.getChildAt(0)).setChecked(true);
                prevChecked = ((RadioButton) linearLayout.getChildAt(0));
            }

            String plan;
            if(prevChecked.getId()==R.id.plan_weekly){
                plan = getString(R.string.weekly);
            }else if(prevChecked.getId()==R.id.plan_biweekly){
                plan = getString(R.string.biweekly);
            }else{
                plan = getString(R.string.one_time);
            }

            getSideBar(plan);

        }

        private void setPrice(){
            try {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
                String date = dateFormater.format(sdf.parse(className.getBooked_date()));
                String time = timeFormater.format(sdf.parse(className.getBooked_date()));

                dateTextView.setText(date);
//HERE THE MAIN ERROR, I GET NULL POINTER EXCEPTION (at getActivity())
                timeTextView.setText(time+" - "+getActivity().getString(R.string.general_cleaning_duration_value, generalCleaning.getDuration()));

                priceTextView.setText(className.getPrice());

            } catch (ParseException pe) {
                pe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private void setRadioButton(){
            //codes
        }


    }
```

Hope you all understand my question, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why mu question get so many downvotes.

I found my answer, I add this code to my 7thFragment and I replace getActivity() with myActivity. Everything works fine.

```
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        myActivity = (MyActivity) context;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            myActivity = (MyActivity) activity;
        }
    }
```

Hope this help you